# Limit choices to foreignkey in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to limit images of request.user to be linked with node. I wish I could do something like:

```
photo = models.ForeignKey(
    Image,
    limit_choices_to={'owner': username},
)
```

but request.user rather than username and I don't want to use local threads.

models.py

```
class Node(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field('owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('file', 'owner')

class NodeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ('content', 'photo', 'owner')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would deal with this by overriding `get_serializer_class` to dynamically return a serializer class at runtime, setting the `choices` option on the field there:

```
def get_serializer_class(self, ...):
    user = self.request.user
    owner_choices = ...  # However you want to restrict the choices

    class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        owner = serializers.Field('owner.username', choices=owner_choices)

        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = ('file', 'owner')

    return ImageSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for your amazing work.

Comment: Is this still the best way of doing it? Seems kinda messy. Would rather have my serializers in global scope, where they can be imported and tested

Comment: `serializers.Field`'s constructor doesn't seem to have the `choices` argument anymore

Answer (score 10):

You can create a custom foreign key field and define `get_queryset()` method there to filter related objects to only those of your user. The current user can be retrieved from the request in the context:

```
class UserPhotoForeignKey(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Image.objects.filter(owner=self.context['request'].user)

class NodeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    photo = UserPhotoForeignKey()
    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ('content', 'photo', 'owner')
```

*This example is using Django REST Framework version 3.*

Answer (score 4):

```
class CustomForeignKey(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Table.objects.filter(is_active=True)

class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (...)
   table= CustomForeignKey()
   class Meta:
   (...)
```

even more easy is :

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (...)
    table = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Table.objects.filter(is_active=True)) 
    class Meta:
    (...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I am sure this logic will be used across an entire Django application why not make it more generic?

```py
class YourPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
        assert hasattr(self.model, 'owner')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=self.context['request'].user)
```

serializers.py

```py
class SomeModelSerializersWithABunchOfOwners(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    photo = YourPrimaryKeyRelatedField(model=Photo)
    categories = YourPrimaryKeyRelatedField(model=Category,
                                            many=True)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomForeignKey(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Table.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
        # or: ...objects.filter(user=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()(self))

class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   table = CustomForeignKey()
```