# Django rest model with foreign key access

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
   class PortalContent(models.Model):
        movies =  models.ForeignKey(Movie, db_column="movies_id")
        portalID = models.IntegerField()
        projectID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        contentType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        licenseTerms = models.TextField()
        createDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have the above model .This model has a field which is related to Movie Model via foreign key.

```
Now when I view the list /portalContent/1/
```

the data takes more than 2 seconds to load . The movie table only has 20K records . 
Not sure why this is taking so much time . I used the debug_toolbar and its showing one query i.e select * from movies as taking 1.6s . Both the tables have index defined .

Can anyone guide me

Comment: Are you using the browsable admin interface? If you are... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173425/limit-choices-to-foreignkey-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Demux

We need to remove browsable API renderer from your list of supported renderers for the view.

You can do this globally like so:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

Or on a per-view basis like so:

```
class MyView(...):
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
```